# Azure Application Gateway CSS/JS header issue

Tags: azure, networking, routes, azure-application-gateway

### Update

I have found, that the configuration is "correct", in that the application gateway properly routes to the correct backend when using the "/payment" path. On the app in question however, the path is still "/payment" which obviously does not work. I know I can circumvent this by using Override Backend Path to "/", but then, as said, the app does not load any CSS / JS files because it looks on the root of the host (I think)

I have a setup going with Azure Application Gateway for a project I am working on currently.

#### Setup

The basic setup goes like this:
Public IP --> Appliction Gateway --> Private Endpoints --> WebApps.

I have enabled multi-site hosting, have given an Azure domain (.cloudapp.azure.com) and have enabled path based routing.
So for example mydomain.germanywestcentral.cloudapp.azure.com/payment will route to a certain backend.

#### Issue

The issue is, while the HTML is loading just fine, all the CSS/JS is not looking at
"mydomain.germanywestcentral.cloudapp.azure.com/payment/site/style.css"
but at
"mydomain.germanywestcentral.cloudapp.azure.com/site/style.css"

I already googled for hours how to solve this issue but to no avail. I realize Azuer is one of the lesser used clouds as of now, but hopefully someone here can, at least in concept, explain what is happening and what needs to be done. Any pointers are helpful here :)

#### Disclaimer

I am rather new to the whole networking topic and Azure, so I am not sure how to solve this issue. How do I tell the app to not look at the root, but at the /payment. If I go to "mydomain.germanywestcentral.cloudapp.azure.com/site/style.css" it loads the file just fine.

#### Note

One thing: In order for any of this to work, I had to set "Override Backend Path" to "/", which is probably what is causing the issue.
However, if I turn this off, it does not load anything, and instead fails loading the site altogether.

#### Images of the settings

- [HTTP Setting for Payment Backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/982WL.png)
- [Listener Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbnO2.png)
- [Rule Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiFDK.png)

Comment: I already tried a load of configurations, but either I am getting 502s, 404s, 400s or straight up no direct code from the probes. I tried using backend override so it at least loads the page, but this then resulted in bad routing for all other files.

Comment: How are the script referenced in your HTML code? sounds like there is something like a src="/myscript.js" which then tries to load from root..

Comment: Its ~/pathToFile.ext because it is a C# application. I know that "/path" would look at the root. so that is not the cause I think.

Comment: and which link do you see, if you view the sourcecode of the page? to me it looks like the application doesn't know about the prefix. so more an application problem than a network/agw issue

Comment: well the link does not contain a prefix, probably because subquent requests from the app get routed to the root of the domain, missing the prefix and thus also missing the path based routing. problem is, if i turn off the backend override "/" it does not load the page at all.